# How to divide a BigInteger by integer?

Tags: java, int, biginteger

(EDIT: Before more people downvote, I did look at the Javadoc beforehand but since I'm a beginner I wasn't sure where in the document to look. See my response to Jim G, which is posted below. I understand that this question is maybe viewed as too basic. But I think it has some value for other beginners in my situation. So please, consider the full situation from a beginner's perspective before downvoting.)

I want to divide a BigInteger by a regular integer (i.e. int) but I don't know how to do this. I did a quick search on Google and on Stack Exchange but didn't find any answers.

So, how can I divide a BigInteger by an int? And while we're at it, how can I add/subtract BigInts to ints, compare BigInts to ints, et cetera?

Comment: Please read the [Javadoc for `BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: Convert the int to a BigInteger, and then use the various methods that take a BigInteger argument

Comment: Thanks Jim and yshavit, will do.

Comment: Why is everyone downvoting? Can someone at least tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Your question comes across as too lazy to read the basic documentation that is freely available.  If you want to be a developer you need to learn how to find answers for yourself, and teach yourself something in the process.  I know it's easier to just post on SO, but you will find yourself with a question for which a quick answer is not forthcoming, and if you don't develop your self-education skills you'll stumble badly.  This question is _so basic_ that it is not a good fit here.  You might try reading the [help] and especially [ask].

Comment: OK Jim, I looked at the Javadoc after reading Kaushal's answer and I understand now; I should have went directly to the "constructor" section of the doc to look for my information. Frankly, there's no way I would have known this without Kaushal's help. What I did earlier (before even posting this question) was to do a Ctrl+F search of the Javadoc looking for "integer", and this of course was not effective, because it didn't occur to me as a beginner that I had to first turn the integer into a string (i.e. to look at "constructors").

Comment: see the edits @ANteelauhFarnese

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `BigInteger.valueOf(long)` factory method. An int can be implicitly "widened" to be long... This is always the case when going from smaller to large, e.g. byte => short, short => int, int => long.

```
BigInteger bigInt = BigInteger.valueOf(12);
int regularInt = 6;

BigInteger result = bigInt.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(regularInt));

System.out.println(result); // => 2
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I didn't realize prior to this that ints were longs. But Kaushal's answer was very helpful too, in that it made me realize the need to look at the "constructors" section in the Javadoc.

Comment: @ANteelauhFarnese updated answer... An int can be implicitly "widened" to be long... This is always the case when going from smaller to large, e.g. byte => short, short => int, int => long.

Comment: Thanks; does this mean that ints are not technically considered longs, but can be treated as such by the program?

Comment: @ANteelauhFarnese Precisely

Answer (score -2):

Convert the `Integer` to `BigInteger` and than divide both `BigInteger`, as following:

```
BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(10);
int x = 6;

//convert the integer to BigInteger.

BigInteger converted = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(x));
//now you can divide, add, subtract etc.

BigInteger result = b.divide(converted);  //but this will give you Integer values.

System.out.println(result);

result = b.add(converted);

System.out.println(result);
```

Above division will give you `Integer` values of divisions, to get exact values, use `BigDecimal`.

**EDIT:**

To remove two intermediate variables `converted` and `result` in above code:

```
BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(10);
int x = 6;

System.out.println(b.divide(new BigInteger(Integer.toString(x))));
```

**OR**

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf((in.nextInt())).divide(new   BigInteger(Integer.toString(in.nextInt()))));
```

Comment: Don't convert from `int` to `BigInteger` via `String`, use `BigInteger.valueOf(long)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Kaushal; but, can you explain what the line "BigInteger converted = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(x));" does?

Comment: But he has asked to Divide BigInteger with Integer , So I assumed he has Integers rather than long

Comment: Btw, it was not me who downvoted your answer; I don't even have the privilege yet

Comment: Yes, Kaushal is right;  I did mean integers rather than long.

Comment: @ANteelauhFarnese  That line converts your Integer to the BigInteger by converting it into the String. Because `BigInteger converted = new BigInteger()`; takes `String` as parameters. So first you have to convert your Integer to the string.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you.

Comment: This was an instructive answer, but in the end I had to choose Adam's because it's the most straightforward approach. I don't know why it got a downvote, but when my rep gets high enough I'll come back and upvote your answer.